# Cordova Push + Azure Notification Hub

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to connect my ionic + cordova based hybrid app to Azure Notification Hub (ANH). For now I only have GCM credentials but the purpose is to register APNS credentials soon.

It seems that there are different solutions to connect to ANH via a Cordova App:

- A cordova plugin: https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-azure-notificationhub: did someone already use this? Are there any prerequisites (phonegap-push-plugin for example)?
- The ANH REST API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495627.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223265.aspx: I tried to do a POST to the CreateRegistration endpoint with the data required for Native GCM messages. However I always get a 400 with this error message in the response: **"An invalid tag 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.String]' was supplied. Valid tag characters are alphanumeric, _, @, -, ., : and #."** It seems to be related to the {GCM Registration Id} I'm passing. Whatever I provide, it returns that error. Anyone knows the format of a valid GCM registration id that can be provided to this API?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also working on a Cordova app targeting an Azure App Service that uses push notifications. The plugin I use is the [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) which appears to be a more active GitHub project that the one you cited. So far, it's working for my purposes (which include tag management).

The phonegap-plugin-push does not work by itself, however. It provides services in each mobile environment to allow you to do the registration with the Azure Notification Hub. In particular, the plugin generates the PNS Identifier required by the ANH from each mobile environment - and, of course, it handles the actual delivery of push notifications. You need to combine phonegap-plugin-push with [azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client).

You can also find a more complete example here: [Add Push Notifications to your Apache Cordova App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-push/).